# How to get specific data from object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm a beginner and would like to know how I can get a specific object from an array

I have an Array that looks like this:

```
data {
    "orderid": 5,
    "orderdate": "testurl.com",
    "username": "chris",
    "email": "",
    "userinfo": [
      {
        "status": "processing",
        "duedate": "" ,
      }
    ]
  },
```

To get the data from above I would do something like this:

```
return this.data.orderid
```

But how can I go deeper and get the status in userinfo?

```
 return this.data.orderid.userinfo.status
```

doesn't work... anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Use `this.data.orderid.userinfo[0].status`

Comment: ommit orderid try,  data.userinfo[0].status

Comment: that's not  valid object

Answer (score 2):

A few points:

- `data` is not an array, is an Object (see the curly braces, arrays have squared brackets). To be really precise, your syntax is invalid, but I assume you wanted to type `data = { ... }`, as opposed to `data { ... }`
- Your syntax is almost correct, the only mistake you are making is that `userinfo` is an array, and arrays have numeric indexes (I.e. `array[0]`, `array[1]`). What you are looking for is `this.data.orderid.userinfo[0].status`

Answer (score 1):

Use `data.userinfo[0].status` to get the value (in your case `this.data.userinfo[0].status`)

```js
var data = {
    "orderid": 5,
    "orderdate": "testurl.com",
    "username": "chris",
    "email": "",
    "userinfo": [
      {
        "status": "processing",
        "duedate": "" ,
      }
    ]
  };
  console.log(data.userinfo[0].status);
```

Answer (score 0):

User Info is an array, so you would need to access it using indexer like so:

```
return this.data.userinfo[0].status
```

MDN on arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over data.userinfo (it's an array)

```js
var data = {
    "orderid": 5,
    "orderdate": "testurl.com",
    "username": "chris",
    "email": "",
    "userinfo": [
      {
        "status": "processing",
        "duedate": "" ,
      }
    ]
  };
  
data.userinfo.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.status);
});
```